# conjugacy of complex squaring map?

Tags: complex-numbers, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Defined [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_squaring_map), it seems to me that if you start with a complex pair (z, z*) ie z and its conjugate, and iterate each one the same number of times that the conjugacy of the pair remains?

Possibly depends on where you wrap your angles? Maybe only works if you measure angles (-pi, pi] ie symmetrically?

Comment: Are you asking whether $(z^2)^* = (z^*)^2$, where $*$ is the complex conjugate?  Yes, that's true - it follows from the [formula for the conjugate of a product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Properties). How you define the argument of a complex number isn't relevant here.

Comment: Yeah, it did seem sort of obvious but I guess I'm confused about the fact that repeated applications of the square map should have sensitivity to the starting point.  I guess that that refers to the values that the iterated map visits rather than the properties of pairs of complex numbers

Comment: ok. The answer to the first question in your op is yes, because you can use the formula in my comment repeatedly, and how you define or measure the argument of a complex number doesn't affect the truth of that formula.  But it sounds like you already knew that and your real question is about something different, like sensitivity to initial conditions for the squaring map - maybe you can edit that in.